# Remove category via mediawiki API

Tags: javascript, ajax, mediawiki

Digging around, it seems simple enough to add a category using AJAX via the mediawiki API:

```
var api = new mw.Api();

function addCat( category ) {
    api.postWithToken( "edit", {
        format: 'json',
        action: "edit",
        title: mw.config.get( "wgPageName" ),
        appendtext: category
    } ).done( function( result, jqXHR ) {
        mw.log( "Saved successfully" );
        location.reload();
    } ).fail( function( code, result ) {
        if ( code === "http" ) {
            mw.log( "HTTP error: " + result.textStatus ); // result.xhr contains the jqXHR object
        } else if ( code === "ok-but-empty" ) {
            mw.log( "Got an empty response from the server" );
        } else {
            mw.log( "API error: " + code );
        }
    } );
}
addCat('[[Category:TEST]]');
```

But I don't see any nice way to remove text (ie, the category string added above) using the API.  The only way I can see to do it would be to pull the entire page's markup, strip out the category text, then post the entire remaining text back via the API.  Is there no cleaner way that doesn't run quite that chance of mangling the page?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. Categories are based on the textual representation of the page, so you cannot avoid manipulating that representation. For an example of JavaScript code that does category removal, see [HotCat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:HotCat).